# PrettyFaces pass variables. How to fix it?

Tags: jsf, prettyfaces

I spent a lot of time but I can't fix what exacly I do wrong with PrettyFaces configuration. I have the following rule in `pretty-config.xml`:

```
<url-mapping id="administrator_comments"> 
      <pattern value="/comments/{someVariableName}" /> 
      <view-id value="/faces/backend/comments/comments" />
</url-mapping>
```

and now I would like to test this using following url:

```
http://localhost:8080/myapplication/comments/test
```

and I get `404 NOT FOUND`. What am I doing wrong? I tried everything but can't understand why that happens. I am doing exactly the same `PrettyFaces` examples.

Comment: Your view-id should be suffixed with `.xhtml`, `.jsp` or whatever view technology you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `#` character for the EL expression and the file extension of your view. Try:

```
<url-mapping id="administrator_comments"> 
  <pattern value="/comments/#{someVariableName}" /> 
  <view-id value="/faces/backend/comments/comments.xhtml" />
</url-mapping>
```